# How to create relationships between django models

Tags: django

I have the two models, One is the User model and the other is a Contact model.

The Contact model is as follows:

```
class Contact(models.Model):  
    pass
    user          = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('User'), related_name="user")
    contact       = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('Contact'), related_name="contact")
    created_at    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    is_contact    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Basically, what is does is create a contact for a user. Kind of a friend request and accept simple model. So the loggedIn user(request.user) could be either the contact.user or contact.contact.

And the settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL is a CustomUser model:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="", blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="", blank=True)
```

How can I create a relationship, where I can get a users contact by doing something like this:

```
// get user contacts user=CustomUser.objects.get(pk=1)
user.contacts.objects.all()
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)? Your `user` model instance should already have a related manager `contact_set`. So you could write `user.contact_set.all()`.

Comment: Sorry, `contact_set` is a default name of the related manager. You should use those you specified in `related_name` argument of your `Contact` model.

Comment: Or may be [many to many relationship on self](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical) with `through` model. Are some of these ways suitable for you?

Comment: Your naming is confusing (`contact` field in a `Contact` class), but what you actually want to do is a [`ManyToMany` relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) from `CustomUser` to `CustomUser` using a [`through` table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships).

Comment: @mrEvgenX thank you. I don't mind the many to many relationship...

Answer (score 0):

Typically you query *reverse relations* using the **`related_name`** keyword, which is **`contact_set`** by default:

```
user.contact_set.all()
```

If you want to change the name of this reverse relationship, you need to do so in the **`Contact`** model using **`related_name`**:

```
class Contact(models.Model):  
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="contacts", ...)


user.contacts.all()
```

Comment: Note that the OP wants to get a set of `CustomUser` instances, not `Contact`s.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as @Selcuk mentioned, this will work just if the authenticated user is the user in the contact model. What if the logged-in user is instead a contact?, I should also, get the user from the contact model as contacts.

Comment: @LearnToday The answer is wrong, but it doesn't have anything to do with the authenticated user. In fact, the ORM has no idea of the authentication system.

Comment: @Selcuk can you help with the better approach answer? Thank you. I don't mind rewriting the models...

Comment: @LearnToday See my and mrEvgenX's comments above. There are many examples on StackOverflow and elsewhere.